# Inverse arc for web page corners

Tags: css, rounded-corners

I know how to make an arc in a web corner. For the right section with this arc `)` we can use this code:

```
 border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
```

and for the left section with this arc `(` we can use this code:

```
 border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
```

and thus make this result :  `(_____)`

But how do you make an arc "(" in right corner and ")" in left corner. I can not use -15px for the radius.

The result should be this:   `)_____(`

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution is append some child elements that have the border radius and opposite background to parent:
HTML

```
<div id="test">
    <div class="right_border border"></div>
    <div class="left_border border"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#test {
    background:#CCC;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden
}
div.border {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    background:#FFF;
    width:50%;
}
.left_border {
    left:-25%;
    border-radius: 50%
}
.right_border {
    right:-25%;
    border-radius: 50%
}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/xq3C7/

Answer (score 0):

There is a funky method to do this using css gradients.

Something like this:

```
div {
background:
        -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg,  transparent 10px, #c00 10px),
        -webkit-linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 10px, #c00 10px),
        -webkit-linear-gradient(225deg, transparent 10px, #c00 10px),
        -webkit-linear-gradient(315deg, transparent 10px, #c00 10px);
}
```

See this link:

http://jsfiddle.net/leaverou/EjE7c/light/

And the tutorial:

http://lea.verou.me/2011/03/beveled-corners-negative-border-radius-with-css3-gradients/

There are also jQuery plugins for that, but they seem to be pretty heavy.

You can also fake it using background images, but i guess thats not what you want.